# URL Requests with SSL Pinning in iOS App are failing for few websites

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have an iOS app which has SSL pinning feature for few particular requests. As SSL Pinning is not working due to some reason, I have downloaded SSL Certificates for 3 sites using Firefox browser (or `openssl` command in mac terminal app) and kept in project local folder. Below are the results, when I run from the iOS app.

**URL:** `https://www.google.com/`

**RESULT:** `WORKING with ssl enabled` - I could see some response as HTML data in the console

---

**URL:** `https://www.google.com/`
**RESULT:**
`cancelled
2019-02-14 15:30:27.702813+0530 CertPinning[30996:733590] Task <B7EEA492-BE74-4E2A-9F47-2F8C964B8539>.<1> finished with error - code: -999
2019-02-14 15:30:27.704132+0530 CertPinning[30996:733596] Task <B7EEA492-BE74-4E2A-9F47-2F8C964B8539>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])`

---

**URL:** `https://api.sendgrid.com/`
**RESULT**

 `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600001c7dd10 {Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <F7FF95D3-ADC7-474C-8B38-0ABA09058AA8>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <F7FF95D3-ADC7-474C-8B38-0ABA09058AA8>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}}, StatusCode=0, ResponseText=, ServiceType=Login, URL=https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send}`

---

**Code from dowloaded from GITHUB**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionDelegate {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/") else { return }

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if let data = data, let contents = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                print(contents)
            }

        }

        task.resume()

    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        guard
            challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust,
            let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust,
            SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, nil) == errSecSuccess,
            let serverCert = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0) else {

                reject(with: completionHandler)
                return
        }

        let serverCertData = SecCertificateCopyData(serverCert) as Data

        guard
            let localCertPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "wwwgooglecom", ofType: "crt"),
            let localCertData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localCertPath) as Data?,

            localCertData == serverCertData else {

                reject(with: completionHandler)
                return
        }

        accept(with: serverTrust, completionHandler)

    }

    func reject(with completionHandler: ((URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)) {
        completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
    }

    func accept(with serverTrust: SecTrust, _ completionHandler: ((URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)) {
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: serverTrust))
    }

}
```

---

Why the the errors are seen in the later two requests ?

While sending email using `SendGrid API`, mail isn't being sent, as SSL Pinning is failing.  I am not sure where I am going wrong. If I don't go for SSL Pinning, everything works as expected. Any one faced the same problem before?

Comment: Impossible to say why if you didn't post the code relevant to SSL pinning

Comment: I'd love to see the actual concept of yours about how to plan applying SSL Pinning generally at any random sites – because you may use the wrong terminology here or you have a misconception of what SSL Pinning means.

Comment: @mag_zbc, updated with code and error for sendgrid api

Comment: @holex, I am using Send Grid for sending email from the iOS App itself. It use to work before, now suddenly stopped working. For this, I am trying on different urls, to test if the code works

Comment: @Sravan, you need the new public key (of SendGrid API) for the renewed certificate for any kinda successful pinning – the public keys usually expire after the point and the pinning against such expired keys will fail inevitably.

Comment: @holex Certificates expire, but if they're renewed using the sane certificate request, the public key doesn't change.

Comment: @mag_zbc, that is not specified in the post whether SendGrid used the _same_ certificate request at all – the obvious assumption at this point that the public key _has changed_.

Comment: @holex Not necessarily, he's pinning against a certificate, not public key alone.

Comment: @mag_zbc, that is a much 'worse' scenario from OP's perspective then, because OP definitely needs to update the entire locally stored data of certificate to match the new one.

Comment: @holex, the API Key is working. we have tested this in some other scenario.

Comment: @Sravan, I am talking about the data of embedded certificate – not he API key.